# How can I detect irregularities in a blob?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I want to detect some peaks that my blob. And I want to mark them or draw something to mark their presence.

Sample image:

[image]

I have tried with harris corner detection and edge detection but I couldn't find the way.

Comment: What was your problem?

Comment: You might try smoothing your shape with morphology. Then use cv2.convexityDefects. See examples at https://theailearner.com/2020/11/09/convexity-defects-opencv/ for example or search Google

Comment: Can you share what your expected output looks like? What have you tried? Can you share some of the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).